# how to remove unnecessary properties from user control?

Tags: c#, user-controls, properties

i want to remove unnecessary properties from user control. But I do not know what way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can remove inherited properties from the Properties window with the [Browsable] attribute:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public override bool AutoScroll {
  get { return base.AutoScroll; }
  set { base.AutoScroll = value; }
}
[Browsable(false)]
public new Size AutoScrollMargin {
  get { return base.AutoScrollMargin; }
  set { base.AutoScrollMargin = value; }
}
```

Note the difference between the two, you have to use the "new" keyword if the property isn't virtual.  You can use the [EditorBrowsable(false)] attribute to also hide the property from IntelliSense.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the properties your control inherits from [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx).

You can, of course, remove properties you've created yourself. Just delete them from your source file.